# Resolve route 53 private hosted zone names in my network

Tags: domain-name-system, vpn, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I have created an AWS VPC and connected my network to it over VPN. I have a private hosted zone within route 53 and the DNS records in it resolve fine in my EC2 instances on the same VPC.

Is there any way to resolve these records from my network too, since they are connected over VPN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way is to use the DNS server within the VPC; depending on what DNS server your using in your non-AWS network, there may be a way to configure it to forward requests to the AWS DNS server for the relevant private domain.

Comment: Do you mean I have to set up another DNS server within my VPC to which the one in my network forwards, or can I forward directly to Amazon's nameserver from my network?

Comment: No, I mean that your DNS server *outside* AWS needs to be configured to forward directly to the AWS VPC nameserver, for the relevant domain

Comment: Well that doesn't work apparently private hosted zones resolve only within VPC, not even on VPN. So the solution was to run a DNS server within VPC which forwarded all requests to route 53 and then setup the DNS server in my network to forward all requests to this DNS server.